# how can i get this algorithm to determine the lowest student mark in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

how do i get an algorithm to determine the lowest mark? i cant figure out how to setup the array so any help is appreciated.

To give you some detail, im having to create an array inside a for loop which determines the students lowest mark recoreded, if the lowest mark is less than the lowest value (line 31) then it updates the lowest value.

the first algorithm begins on line 91, if anyone can give me some support with this one i will be able to complete the second

```
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int maxNumberOfMarks = 5; // allows up to 5 marks to be stored, this value can be updated
    int[] studentMarks = new int[5]; // array to store each student mark


    int count = 0; // keeps count of the number of student marks entered
    int index = 0; // used to access the array

    //Declare lowest and set value to 1000
    int lowest = 1000;
    int highest = 0;
    //Declare highest and set to 0


    // Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // This method is used to add a student mark to the array
    // A mark can only be added if there is space left in the array 
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if we have already stored the max. number of marks
        if (count < maxNumberOfMarks)
        {
            // grab the mark out of the textbox and add it into the 
            // next free index in the array
            studentMarks[count] = int.Parse(txtMark.Text);

            count++; // update the count to indicate a mark has been added to the array

            txtMark.Text = ""; // clear the textbox now that the mark has been added

            txtMark.Focus(); // puts the cursor back in the textbox so user can add more marks

        }
        else
        {
            // we have reached the max number of marks we can store in the array
            MessageBox.Show("List Full");
            txtMark.Text = "";
        }
    }


    // this method clears all of the textblock summary data and resets the count
    // of student marks to 0, so the user can enter a new set of student data
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count = 0;
        blkNumberOfMarks.Text = "";
        blkMarksTotalled.Text = "";
        blkHighest.Text = "";
        blkLowest.Text = "";
        blkMarksTotalled.Text = "";
    }

    // this method calculates and displays all of the summary data based on the
    // student marks stored in the studentMarks array
    private void btnSummary_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // initialise the variables being used to store the summary data
        int totalStudentMarks = 0;
        float average;

        try
        {
            /*Algorithm to determine the lowest student mark, change this to code **********
             * 
             * N.B. count stores the number of student marks recorded and index is used to access the array
             * 
             * For index=0 up to count 
             *   If value at studentMarks[index] is less than lowest
             *       update lowest to be the value from studentMarks[index] 
             *   End of the If
             * End of the loop
             ************************************************************ */



            /*Algorithm to determine the highest student mark, change this to code **********
            *  
            * N.B. count stores the number of student marks recorded and index is used to access the array
            * 
            * For index=0 up to count 
            *   If value at studentMarks[index] is higher than highest
            *       update highest to be the value from studentMarks[index] 
            *   End of the If
            * End of the loop 
            ************************************************************ */



            if (count > 0)
            {
                // calculate all of the statistics to be displayed in the 
                // summary textblocks
                average = totalStudentMarks / count;
                blkNumberOfMarks.Text = count.ToString();
                blkMarksTotalled.Text = totalStudentMarks.ToString();
                blkAverage.Text = average.ToString();
                blkHighest.Text = highest.ToString();
                blkLowest.Text = highest.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not enough Data Entered");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must be numeric!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *on line 91* - stack overflow code blocks do not have line numbers

Comment: The algorithm text seems sound, you just don't appear to have written any code. Are you asking because you want someone to write it for you, or did you forget to add the code you want help with?

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry... first time using this website! line 91 is the first algorithm comment "/*algorithm to determine the lowest student mark" thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @CaiusJard im just needing some help with the code, ive tried it a few times but keep messing it up, i figured adding in the comment will help explain what im asking for.